# Exact string match in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file test.txt with the next lines

```
1997           100   500   2010TJ
2010TJXML      16    20    59
```

I'm using the next awk line to get information only about string 2010TJ

```
awk -v var="2010TJ" '$0 ~ var {print $0}' test.txt
```

But the code print the two lines. I want to know how to get the line containing the exact string

```
1997  100   500   2010TJ
```

the string can be placed in any column of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several options:

Use a `gawk` word boundary (not POSIX awk...):

```
$ gawk '/\<2010TJ\>/' file
```

An actual space or tab or what is separating the columns:

```
$ awk '/^2010TJ /' file
```

Or compare the field directly to the string:

```
$ awk '$1=="2010TJ"' file
```

You can loop over the fields to test each field if you wish:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="2010TJ") {print; next}}' file
```

Or, given your example of setting a variable, those same using a variable:

```
$ gawk -v s=2010TJ '$0~"\\<" s "\\>"' 
$ awk -v s=2010TJ '$0~"^" s " "'
$ awk -v s=2010TJ '$1==s'
```

Note the first is a little different than the second and third. The first is the standalone string `2010TJ` anywhere in `$0`; the second and third is a string that starts with that string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for testing only column 1) :

```
awk '$1 == "2010TJ" {print $0}' test.txt
```

or grep like (all columns) :

```
gawk '/\<2010TJ\>/ {print $0}' test.txt
```

### Note

```
\< \> is word boundarys
```

Comment: If the string is not in at the first field 2010TJ         100   500   200
2010TJXML      16    20    59

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` with word boundary

```
awk '/\y2010TJ\y/' file
```

note `\y` matches either beginning or end of a word.